# filter and map in one? (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

The problem:

```
def detect_monitors_and_modes(preferred_order, binp):
    out = run_xrandr(binp)
    findit = partial(get_mon_mode, preferred_order)
    print 'OUTPUT', '\n'.join(out)
    lst = map(findit, out)
    print 'lst', lst
    matches = filter(lambda x: x, lst)
    print 'matches', matches


OUTPUT Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.1*+   40.1
   1360x768       59.8     60.0
   1024x768       60.0
   800x600        60.3     56.2
   640x480        59.9
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

lst [None, 'LVDS1', '1366x768', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
matches ['LVDS1', '1366x768']
```

Specifically, I wonder if there is a shorter/more idiomatic way to do this:

```
lst = map(findit, out)
matches = filter(lambda x: x, lst)
```

Obviously, I can't use just `filter` bc this would return entire line (`LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal...`) instead of value returned by `findit`. And `map` returns `None`s for lines that do not match.

(is there some use for `reduce` here? but since it's not kosher..)

EDIT: I want to filter out "falsy" values here, that is, empty strings, `None`s, `False` and so on, leave only what `findit` finds as positive match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to filter out "falsy" values here, that is, empty strings, Nones, False and so on, leave only what findit finds as positive match.

You could simplify to:

```
matches = filter(None, map(findit, out))
```

as per the docs:

> If *function* is `None`, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of *iterable* that are false are removed.

For reference:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter

Comment: I think I prefer `filter(bool, map(findit, out))` because it feels less magical than the `None` shortcut.

Comment: You could also use a list comprehension `[x for x in map(findit, out) if x]`, if you prefer to. But there's no sane way around the `map()` I think.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is, using list comprehensions

```
matches = [findit(x) for x in out if findit(x) is not None]
```

This is the "pythonic" way to do it as described by the PEP's

Comment: I'm not sure this is Pythonic really - doing findit(x) twice (needlessly) violates DRY.

Comment: To avoid that repetition, `[y for x in out for y in [findit(x)] if y is not None]`, though this doesn't really show list comprehensions at their best. I haven't use Python for a while, but that should work - basically iterating a single-item list in order to bind that variable. There's probably a better way, but I don't remember it.

Comment: @Steve: I like list comprehensions but this is pushing it. ;-) (it could be made slightly better by omitting `is not None` part I think)

Comment: @John Doe - There's always `[x for x in [findit(y) for y in out] if x is not None]` - a fairly direct transliteration of the map+filter version. I don't remember why the `is not None` is there and am too lazy to work it out, so it stays in (a phrase that explains about 90% of old code, and at least 99.9% of the comments).

Comment: The `is not None` makes it more readable.

Comment: @DuncanMacIntyre That's not true... Let's take `x = 0` for example. If you write `is not None`, then `x`'s value will be added to the list. However, if you only write `if x`, then `x`'s value won't be added to the list. The reason is that `x`'s type is not `None`, but when you convert `0` to `bool` the result is `False`.